# Как сохранить данные из ответа веб-сокета, после отправки запроса в UI тесте, выполненном в pytest

Tags: python, selenium, websocket, selenium-webdriver, pytest

UI test выполняется в pytest (тест выполнентся хорошо)

`from page_objects import MainPage, LoginPage`

`def test_locate_best_accept(browser):`

`LoginPage(browser) \`

```
.login_user(login='****_user', password="******")`
```

`MainPage(browser) \`

```
.select_symbol(symbol='ACY') \
.select_quantity_symbol(quantity=600) \
.select_destination_best() \
.click_request_button() \
.accept_request()`
```

После выполнения шага «.click_request_button ()» мне нужно получить и сохранить данные  из ответа WebSockets в «словарь Python». Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось получить ответ WebSocet в терминале использовав библиотеку Pyppeteer

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import time
import pprint
import json


async def test():
    args = ['--start-maximized']
    browser = await launch(
        args=args,
        headless=False,
        # args=['--no-sandbox'],
        # autoClose=False
        )

    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://example.com/')
    await page.setViewport({'width': 1920, 'height': 1080})

    # create CDP Session
    cdp = await page.target.createCDPSession()
    await cdp.send('Network.enable')

    #  Login
    await page.type('input[name=login]', 'login')
    await page.type('input[name=password]', 'password')
    await page.click('button[type=submit]')
    time.sleep(2)

    # Fill in the request
    await page.type('input[name=symbol]', 'ACY')
    await page.type('input[name=quantity]', '500')
    await page.click('selector')
    await page.type('selector', 'Text')
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')
    await page.click('button[type=submit]')

    # Waiting for the status of "Pending"
    await page.waitForSelector('selector, {'timeout': 5000})

    def printResponse(response):
        pprint.pprint(response)

    # Calls printResponse when a websocket is received
    cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', printResponse) 

    # Calls printResponse when a websocket is sent 
    # cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', printResponse)  

    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    # await page.close()
    # await browser.close()


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_best_location_accept())
```